# Add shadow to a UITabbar in iOS8

Tags: swift, ios8, uikit, ios9, uitabbar

I wanna add a simple shadow to my UITabbar. 
I added a shadow image (a 10x1 gradient) to my project / related storyboard property.

The image should be repeated by itself, shouldn't it?

Nevertheless, there is no shadow in the design mode as well no shadow if I launch the application.

Would could be wrong?

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: As you are using shadow image it should be seen when you launch the application. Only if :

1. You have an autolayout issue I mean somehow the image is going under other views.
2. Or your image height is very less. ~ 1-2 pixels.

You should attach both screenshot and the shadow image in this question. Otherwise I will not able to help you.

Comment: Sorry, that is not possible. But I found a solution. I'll post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keep in mind:

1. read
2. understand

**To use an image shadow you have to set a background image.**

I used a simple transparent / bg-colored 16x16 image.

After that, the the shadow appeared.

Comment: I have given the answer assuming you already added a imageview. Looks like you just started ios development.

Comment: Sorry. This was not indented. Yes, you are right. I'm new to the iOS development.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done programatically also:

```
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.shadowColor = CustomColors.Graphites.dark.cgColor
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: -4.0)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.layer.shadowRadius = 3
```